# How do I change the default link type for the "Get A Link" option?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration

Microsoft says that you can change the default link type in SharePoint libraries via the Admin -> Admin Centers -> SharePoint -> Sharing menu option.  When I try this on my SharePoint Online site there is not option to change the default link type.  What is the correct way to set the default link type?

Here is the Microsoft article which gives these instructions, but the option to change the default link type is not present: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-default-link-type-when-users-get-links-for-sharing-81b763af-f301-4226-8842-8d13bd07face

Here is a screen shot of my Sharing menu options:

[image: Sharing options]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must first select a different option in the first section, e.g. "Don't allow sharing outside your organization" and THEN you will see the Default link type selection.

Comment: No, this is not correct.  I tried it and the Additional Settings and Notifications sections go away and no Default Link type setting appears.